# Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. while setting apache-cassandra-3.11.8

Tags: cassandra, jvm

I am getting this error messege when I am typing `cassandra` on my cmd.

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

my java version is

```
java version "15" 2020-09-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am using windows 10 and both are installed on C drive. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: To be specific, `-XX:+UseParNewGC` (as specified in the `jvm.options` file) is not a valid option for Java 15.  As Alex stated, Cassandra 3.x only works with Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 issues:

1. Windows clearly says you to execute `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` to be able to run the startup script
2. You're using Java 15 that is not supported by Cassandra 3.11 - it works only with Java 8, so you need to downgrade Java

P.S. I would recommend to run Cassandra in Docker on Windows - you'll avoid many problems, as Windows isn't very actively supported platform for Cassandra, and [its support could be removed in the future](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/rb56e3ff7ca2e15cd90884802f2027c6f78f99c667420ae0f774109b8%40%3Cdev.cassandra.apache.org%3E).